# PHP need to get an object's property value, but the property has a complicated key

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, object

I was surprised how complicated this became.  I am using this code as a mysql row fetch:

```
$query_start_date = "SELECT MIN(date) FROM table";
$database->setQuery($query_start_date);
$start2 = $database->loadObjectList();
var_dump($start2);
```

And I get this result (which seems good because it contains the expected data):

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#7346 (1) { ["MIN(date)"]=> string(19) "2008-11-03 10:53:32" } }
```

But now, I need to put that date `2008-11-03 10:53:32` into another simple variable.  I've tried many things; the below test seems like the closest:

```
echo $start2[0]->MIN(date);
```

But for that I get the error:
    Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::MIN() in ...

Can anyone please show me how to get that date value and place it into a variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a curly `{}` brace to access that property:

```
echo $start2[0]->{'MIN(date)'};
```

Or just use an alias and use that to your convinience:

```
SELECT MIN(date) AS mydate FROM `table`
```

So that you'll just access `->mydate`.

Comment: Yes!  And do know where I can learn more about these curly braces, and how they work?

Comment: @JoeCool here's an entry in the manual regarding additional information http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex